# PHP can't print array elements without using print_r

Tags: php, arrays

I am using a db query that takes in a state and city then spits out 10 fields. Currently I can only see those fields by using print_r. I tried a suggestion on the [php manual site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php) a for loop to print the fields however I can't get it to work properly. Here is the code:

```
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            print_r($row)."</p>";
            $arrayLength = count($row);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++){
                echo "arrayName at[" . $i . "] is: [" .$row[$i] . "]<br>\n";
            }
                
                
        }

    }
```

And this is the result:

```
Array ( [id] => 1299 [zip_code] => 04011 [city] => Brunswick [county] => Cumberland [state_name] => Maine [state_prefix] => ME [area_code] => 207 [time_zone] => Eastern [lat] => 43.9056 [lon] => -69.9646 ) ....
arrayName at[0] is: []
arrayName at[1] is: []
arrayName at[2] is: []
arrayName at[3] is: []
arrayName at[4] is: []
arrayName at[5] is: []
arrayName at[6] is: []
arrayName at[7] is: []
arrayName at[8] is: []
arrayName at[9] is: []
```

Any ideas why I am not able to properly print the fields and their values? Also my code fails if the query returns more than one row as the current code doesn't really accommodate it.

I put $i in the body of the for loop to see if it was working properly. Ideally I would have the field name where $i is and the value to the right of it after the colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are fetching with mysql_fetch_assoc so 
change loop into

```
foreach($row as $key => $value){
echo "Array key : $key = $value <br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your array keys are `'id'`, `'zip_code'` etc. There's nothing in the `0`, `1` etc. indexes of the array.

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    echo "arrayName at[" . $key . "] is: [" . $value . "]<br>\n";
    // which is the same as:
    echo "arrayName at[" . $key . "] is: [" . $row[$key] . "]<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because that returns an associative array
That means that you have to access the elements like so:
$row["id"] for instance

What you want is this

```
foreach($row as $key => $value)
echo "arrayName at[" . $key . "] is: [" .$value . "]<br>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_fetch_array() instead of mysql_fetch_assoc()

the mysql_fetch_assoc() will return an associative array and only accessable via $row['name'].
With mysql_fetch_array() you can fetch an associative array, a numeric array, or both.

take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php